# sort/lexsort/bincount/etc. for arrays that don't fit in memory

Tags: python, numpy, bigdata

I'm trying to scale up a library written in numpy so that it can process  arrays that don't fit in memory (~10 arrays of 10 billion elements)

hdf5 (h5py) was a temporary solution, but I rely heavily on sorting and indexing (b = a[a>5]), which are both not available in h5py and are a pain to write.

Is there a library that would made these tools available?

Specifically I need basic math, sort, lexsort, argsort, bincount, np.diff, and indexing (both boolean and with the array of indices).

Answer (score 1):

[PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/) is designed precisely for this (also based on `hdf5`). First store your array to disk

```
import numpy as np
import tables as tb

# Write big numpy array to disk
rows, cols = 80000000, 2
h5file = tb.open_file('test.h5', mode='w', title="Test Array")
root = h5file.root
array_on_disk = h5file.create_carray(root,
         'array_on_disk',tb.Float64Atom(),shape=(rows,cols))
# Fill part of the array
rand_array = np.random.rand(1000)
array_on_disk[10055:11055] = rand_array
array_on_disk[12020:13020] = 2.*rand_array  
h5file.close()
```

Then perform your computation directly on the array (or part of it) contained in the file

```
h5file = tb.open_file('disk_array.h5', mode='r')
print h5file.root.array_on_disk[10050:10065,0]
# in-place sort
h5file.root.array_on_disk[100000:10000000,:].sort(axis=0)
h5file.close()
```